# AngularJS ngModel doesn't work inside a ui-bootstrap tabset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

The following code illustrates the problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.changes = 0;
  $scope.updateValueInScope = function () {
    $scope.valueInScope = $scope.value;
    $scope.changes++;
  }
});
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tabset>
      <tab heading="Tab A">
        <div class="panel">
          <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-change="updateValueInScope()" />
          <br />
          <tt>value: {{value}}</tt><br />
          <tt>valueInScope: {{valueInScope}}</tt><br />
          <tt>changes: {{changes}}</tt>
        </div>
      </tab>
    </tabset>
    <input type="text" ng-model="value" ng-change="updateValueInScope()" />
    <br />
    <tt>value: {{value}}</tt><br />
    <tt>valueInScope: {{valueInScope}}</tt><br />
    <tt>changes: {{changes}}</tt>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dJc009csXVHc7PLSyCf4?p=preview

This creates two textboxes, one inside the tabset, and one outside. They are both bound to the `value` scope variable. Updating the contents of the textbox inside the tabset does not update the `value` variable in the scope. Updating the textbox outside the tabset does. Changes to either of the textboxes will result in a call to `updateValueInScope()` via ngChange.

Can someone explain to me why this behaves this way? Is there some way to "fix" the behavior so that the textbox inside the tabset will modify the model in the scope?

Comment: It works fine without the angualar-ui injection.  Maybe a bug in angular-ui?

Comment: I agree. It works fine without angular-ui, hence my confusion. Also, it's very close to the example given in the ngModel documentation: [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel). Even so, reptilicus' answer fixed the problem for me, so I have marked it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Almost certainly the issue is that you are trying to bind to a primitive (in this case a float). Something like this should fix it.

```
$scope.data = {}
$scope.updateValueInScope = function () {
  $scope.data.valueInScope = $scope.data.value;
  $scope.changes++;
}
```

Basically in angular, if you bind to a primitive the value of the variable is passed around, and not the reference to it, which can break 2-way binding. I'm guessing that the `tabset` directive creates its own scope, so the `valueInScope` variable defined in the controller loses its binding in the child scope of the `tabset` because its a primitive. Anyway, don't bind to primitives and it should work.

Here is a [fixed version of plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/toaHYASwbP9iWFvDXGmu?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation. That helps.

Comment: Excellent, that was the issue. Primitives break 2 way data-binding for isolated scopes, so we better use an object to prevent this from happening thank you very much @reptilicus.